# Haskell class definition question about restrictions

Tags: haskell

```
class IndexSelect k (m :: k -> (* -> *) -> *) | m -> k where
    type Restriction m (p :: k) :: Constraint
    indexSelect :: Restriction m p => Sing (p :: k) -> Proxy m -> LocalDb f -> f (TableEntity (m p))
```

I'm new to the Haskell language. I'm having trouble deciphering the class definition in some code in the code repo at the company I just started at.
What is this doing?

Comment: This is a _very_ complex definition - I'm struggling to understand it! Here's some links to look through which may help, especially the first two: https://diogocastro.com/blog/2018/10/17/haskells-kind-system-a-primer/, https://blog.jle.im/entry/introduction-to-singletons-1.html, https://wiki.haskell.org/Multi-parameter_type_class, https://wiki.haskell.org/Functional_dependencies

Comment: Just to make it very clear since you're new to Haskell, the code you're looking at is *very* expert Haskell code and is not the sort of thing you run into everyday, so not understanding it is totally normal. If I (a Haskell programmer going on five years) saw this in the wild without any comments, I wouldn't know what to do with it either.

Comment: I fear it will be impossible to provide a fully satisfactory answer here on SO for this question, since it involves a lot of advanced Haskell concepts (type classes with multiple args, fundeps, `Constraint` kind, type families, higher kinds, kind polymorphism, GADTs and singletons, proxies). Explaining this in detail so that a beginner could have a chance to understand would amount to writing a book. At best, be prepared for answers containing a lot of pointers to advanced stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a lot going on here.  I am going to start by referring you to Sections [7.6 Class and Instance Declarations](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/type-class-extensions.html), [7.7 Type Families](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/type-families.html), and [7.8.4 Explicitly-kinded qualifications](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.1/docs/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html#kinding) of the GHC language extension documentation.  (I am by no means an expert on any of these and clicked on your question hoping someone had supplied further enlightenment.)

We are defining a multi-parameter type class called `IndexSelect` with parameters `k` and `m`. (Multi-parameter type classes 7.6.1.1)

The second parameter of the class, `m`, is given an explicit kind qualification: `k -> (* -> *) -> *` in English `m` must be a function which takes a `k` and a function and returns a value. (7.8.4 Explicitly-kinded quantification)

The class has a functional dependency `| m -> k`. Where the choice of `m` must uniquely determine `k` Given the name of this function that implies that a collection `m` must have only one kind of key `k` which is reasonable. (7.6.2 Functional Dependencies)

The class forms a indexed type family `type Restriction m (p :: k) :: Constraint`. It appears inside a class definition so it is an associated type synonym. (7.7.2.1.1 Associated type family declarations). It takes some `m` and a `p` which must be of type `k` and results in a Constraint.

The class has one listed method `indexSelect` which one might guess manages to extract information from a collection.  Without knowing what `Sing`, `LocalDb` and `TableEntity` do I cannot say more.

Comment: I'm guessing that `Sing` is from the [`singletons`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/singletons) package.

Comment: NOTE: I know that the bit on type families is not functionally very useful. It is really just  α reduction of the Type Family manual entry.  Anyone who can explain what this type family accomplishes please chime in.

Comment: Thank you so much John. I really appreciate your time and knowledge in answering my question.